# GROUP BY multiple row and want to show more than 1 record

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a `store` table, and the sql is

```sql
SELECT * FROM `store` GROUP BY `store_name`, `country`, `branch`
```

The output is

| store_name | country | branch |
| --- | --- | --- |
| store_a | US | New_York |
| store_a | US | Texas |
| store_b | Japan | Tokyo |
| store_c | German | Hamburg |
| store_c | German | Berlin |
| store_c | German | Hesse |
| store_d | French | Paris |

Now I want to show stores have more than 1 branches

This is what I expect:

| store_name | country | branch |
| --- | --- | --- |
| store_a | US | New_York |
| store_a | US | Texas |
| store_c | German | Hamburg |
| store_c | German | Berlin |
| store_c | German | Hesse |

How to achieve this?

Comment: 1. If there are more than the three columns in the table, then `SELECT * FROM store GROUP BY store_name, country, branch` is invalid. If there are just the three columns in the table, then your query can be simplified to `SELECT * FROM store`. 2. In your sample data the same store name happens to be in the same country always. But what about the same store name in two different countries? Do you conisder these two rows for the store and show the rows or one row per store/country and you don't show the rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution using [window functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions.html) (you must use MySQL 8.0 for this feature):

```
select store_name, country, branch from (
  select store_name, country, branch, 
    count(*) over (partition by store_name) as count
  from store
) as t
where count > 1;
```

No GROUP BY is needed.

Answer (score 2):

That is what the `HAVING` clause is for.

Try

```
SELECT * 
FROM `store` 
GROUP BY `store_name`, `country`, `branch`
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Comment: `SELECT * `  with `GROUP BY  store_name, country, branch` very bad practice, try and run your query on https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0

Comment: @ErgestBasha, can you please explain why is it a bad practice?

Comment: @Asgar you have a detailed explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34115174/error-related-to-only-full-group-by-when-executing-a-query-in-mysql)  and on [MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-handling.html)

Answer (score 0):

Join with a query that gets the number of branches per country and only returns the ones that have more than one branch.

```
SELECT a.*
FROM store AS a
JOIN (
    SELECT store_name, country
    FROM store
    GROUP BY store_name, country
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) AS b ON a.store_name = b.store_name AND a.country = b.country
```